# Are all deductively closed sets be infinite?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I am thinking about this question. I mean, by definition, a deductively closed set must include all formulas which can be entailed from it. So if there exists a finite set which is seductively closed, then for any of its element p, a tautology p -> not p must also in it, because any valuation can satisfy a tautology. Then by doing so, we find that the enclosed formulas are at least countably infinite.

Also, since tautology must be included in a seductively closed set (actually any set), tautologies are obviously infinite, then as a result, a seductively closed set is infinite.

Is it right?

Comment: Depends on your rules of inferences.

Comment: @DanielV Is there any reasonable set of inference rules which doesn't? You'd have to somehow not consider $$(p\rightarrow p)\wedge(p\rightarrow p)\wedge ...\wedge (p\rightarrow p)$$ a tautology, for example, in order to avoid this. I don't know of a single interesting system this happens for.

Comment: What does it mean? I mean, just assume that there exist infinitely many tautologies, in my rules. Then in this case, any deductively closed set must include all of them because the definition is, since any deductively closed set's satisfying valuation will satisfy any tautologies. So is this right?...

Comment: @qwerty Yes, that's right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, any deductively closed set must by definition contain all the tautologies - so if there are infinitely many tautologies, every deductively closed set must be infinite.

A word about the *scope* of this situation: there are lots of logical systems out there, but every single one I know which is at all interesting does indeed have infinitely many tautologies. The only exceptions I know are artificial examples like the system $\mathcal{L}_{stupid}$ with no nontrivial deductions at all: $\Gamma\vdash_{\mathcal{L}_{stupid}}\varphi$ iff $\varphi\in\Gamma$. In $\mathcal{L}_{stupid}$ there are no tautologies - that is, we never have $\emptyset\vdash_{\mathcal{L}_{stupid}}\varphi$) - and indeed every set is deductively closed.

Comment: As an aside, if we're going to talk about exotic logical systems a word should be reserved for **non-monotonic logics**. These are systems in which adding axioms can *remove* theorems - they come up in various ways, but especially when trying to model reasoning from uncertain data. There are now two notions of "tautology," namely "thing deducible from the empty set" and "thing which is deducible from every set of axioms." The latter implies the former of course, but since we're allowing non-monotonicity the reverse doesn't need to hold. The latter is the right notion for questions like the OP.